# Create popover using glade

Tags: gtk, glade

I want to create some popover widget using only glade: is it possible?

By popover I mean some window that shows when clicking on a button and that disappears when clicking elsewhere.

Comment: GTK+ 3.12 adds GtkPopover. More recent versions of glade should have that available (try 3.18?)

Comment: @andlabs I am on glade 3.19, but I cannot see any GtkPopover widget. But I will search everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glade 3.20 adds support for GtkPopover, which itself was added in GTK+ 3.12. You'll have to be careful about making sure your generated .ui files are backward compatible (which includes going in and checking the header of the file).

Comment: After creating a GtkPopover, you need to create a GtkMenuButton, and then you have to select the popover in its use-popover property.

Comment: That's only if you want to use a popover with a GMenu. You don't have to do that; a popover is just a GtkBin so it can contain anything, just like a normal window.

Comment: Yes, but only the GtkMenuButton has the `use-popover` property. I could not find another way to show the popover, using only glade.

Comment: Oh, yes; you need to connect your UI elements using code somehow. Glade doesn't define behavior, only appearance. (It *can* take advantage of GModule features to hook up signals by function name, but other than that :/ )

Comment: Glade has a bug that when you associate the Popover to the MenuButton, it will "disappear" from the main interface but still present on the widgets tree.

Comment: Then report that bug on the GNOME Bugzilla so it can be fixed =P I don't have any control over it myself.